# Solr not querying "\n" correctly

Tags: solr

When I send solr the following query parameters, I get zero records found

```
fq=field1_s:("lorem%20ipsum\nsolor%20sit%20amet")&q=*:*defType=edismax
```

even though there is a record that has the value for field1_s "lorem ipsum\nsolor sit amet"
How do I properly send the "\n" character?
It works for strings that do not have "\n" in them.

Comment: In the end, I found it was not a solr issue, but an issue in my php code generating the parameters.  After encoding and decoding user 
    rawurlencode()
and
    rawurldecode()

    "\n"
was transformed into
    '\n'

In other words, the encoded value of 
    %0A
was transformed into
    %5Cn

Answer (score 0):

**Encode slash `\` to %5C, So Encoding of `\n` will be `%5Cn`**

So your query should be :

```
fq=field1_s:("lorem%20ipsum%5Cnsolor%20sit%20amet")&q=*:*defType=edismax
```

If you are using solrj then you can use `ClientUtils.escapeQueryChars(your_query)` ClientUtils.escapeQueryChars to escape meta character